# Image Not Uploading - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a problem uploading image in a Codeigniter app I'm working on. The code was working when on my pc (ubuntu) just fine, as it's given in tutorials. But when I'm trying this in my (centos) server, it's giving an error
"You did not select a file to upload.".

Just for your reference, I'll paste the code here.

**Controller- Upload1.php**

```
 <?php

 class Upload1 extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('upload_form1', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']     = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form1', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success1', $data);
            }
    }
 }
 ?>
```

**Form - upload_form1.php**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Upload Form</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php echo $error;?>

 <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload1/do_upload');?>

 <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

 <br /><br />

 <input type="submit" value="upload" />

 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**Success Page- upload_success1.php**

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Upload Form</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>

 <ul>
 <?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
 <li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>

 <p><?php echo anchor('upload1', 'Upload Another File!'); ?></p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

What could be the problem? 
I have "uploads" directory set to 777. So that's not likely to be the reason. I also tried couple of solutions to similar problems, but isn't working. Have missed something obvious?

Versions:
For Server- PHP 5.3.13 (cli) 
My PC- PHP 5.3.3 .

Codeigniter is same on local and remote machines- that is 2.1.3

I will be grateful for your suggestions!!

Thank you so much

Comment: This will sound totally illogical, but try replacing the form_open_multipart('upload1/do_upload') with actual html. I recently had an inexplicable problem similar to yours and nothing fixed it until I just wrote the open form tag myself. <form id="upload" action="upload1/do_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @KaiQing OP should first check HTML source to see if the HTML is being output properly to begin with beforehand.

Comment: @cryptic - i did the same. The form tag was being written properly but for some reason it was behaving like it was not even trying to submit data. Like I said - totally illogical, but that's what did it for me.

Comment: @cryptic,@KaiQing With form tags, the html output was- <form action="http://www.example.com/upload1/do_upload" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">, which was not giving results.                             So, I replaced that with    actual html `<form id="upload" action="upload1/do_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`, But no luck...:(

Comment: @user1478061 what are the PHP and CodeIgniter versions for both systems?

Comment: @cryptic, For Server-
PHP 5.3.13 (cli)

My PC-
PHP 5.3.3 . Codeigniter is same on local and remote machines- that is 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

based on your code, i don't see if there is any form validation to validate the submitted input whether it's valid with your upload config or not. What you should do first : Check the file that you're trying to upload is appropriate with the upload config or not. I think CI's upload class doesn't cover errors from a non valid input form. CMIIW.

Comment: thanks, I get what you're trying to say. But I did with an image on local machine with same code, and it got uploaded. But not working on server..

Answer (score 0):

normally this is the error when you are not taking the name as "userfile" so check the output by 'view source' in any browser